# Compare matrices in Python and get location of mismatches

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix

I have two matrices, A and B, and they have the exact same shape. 
I would like to compare these matrices element-wise and store the location of all mismatches. Say that A:

```
[[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]]
```

and B:

```
[[1,2,3],
[3,5,6],
[7,7,9]]
```

The result would then be something like a list with:
lst  = [(2,1),(3,2)]

I'm analysing some pictures, so my matrices are actually 3d (however, I don't think that this will make a huge difference).

Once I have the list with the mismatches, I will then recreate all the mismatching pixels to see their exact differences.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `np.argwhere`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[3, 5, 6], [7,7,9]])

ids = np.argwhere(a!=b) # indexes satisfying the condition

print(ids)
```

output (arrays are indexed from 0):

```
[[1 0]
 [2 1]]
```